# Passing ConnectionString from SqlConnectionSringBuilder to ConnectionManager

Tags: c#, package, connection-string, sqlconnection

I want to get a `ConnectionString` from an instance of `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` as a `String`.

This seems simple, and should be as easy as this:

```
String conString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

However the `String` that `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` gives up doesn't include the `Password` field/value. I'm guessing this is some sort of security feature, is there a way to force `Password` to be included in the `String`?

---

Looking at this further I'm thinking this may have something to do with `ConnectionManager`. What I am trying to do is modify the `ConnectionString` for a `Package`, changing the `Initial Catalog`.

Below is my code, the point that `builder`'s connection string is passed back into `connectionManager`'s the Password is lost...

```
    public void DataTransfer(String sourceConnection, String destConnection, String pkgLocation)
    {     
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;

        try
        {
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

            foreach (ConnectionManager connectionManager in pkg.Connections)
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder;
                switch (connectionManager.Name)
                {
                    case "SourceConnection":
                        builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sourceConnection) { PersistSecurityInfo = true };
                        builder.Remove("Initial Catalog");
                        builder.Add("Initial Catalog", "StagingArea");
                        connectionManager.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString.ToString();
                        connectionManager.ConnectionString += ";Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;";
                        Debug.WriteLine(connectionManager.ConnectionString.ToString());
                        break;
                    case "DestinationConnection":
                        builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sourceConnection) { PersistSecurityInfo = true };
                        builder.Remove("Initial Catalog");
                        builder.Add("Initial Catalog", "StagingArea");
                        connectionManager.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString.ToString();
                        connectionManager.ConnectionString += ";Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;";
                        Debug.WriteLine(connectionManager.ConnectionString.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: In my tests, the Password field always shows up. Maybe you could show us the code you're using to build the connection string?

Comment: @madd0 I've added my code, think the problem might be slightly different. See above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to rename this a little maybe, as the question is different now, but here is my solution:

The first part of this question was answered correctly by @madd0. The `ConnectionString` does contain the `Password` field.

---

The second part was solved with formatting code is below:

```
public void DataTransfer(String sourceConnection, String destConnection, String pkgLocation)
{     
    Package pkg;
    Application app;
    DTSExecResult pkgResults;

    try
    {
        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

        foreach (ConnectionManager connectionManager in pkg.Connections)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder;
            switch (connectionManager.Name)
            {
                case "SourceConnection":
                    builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sourceConnection) { PersistSecurityInfo = true };
                    builder.Remove("Initial Catalog");
                    builder.Add("Initial Catalog", "StagingArea");
                    var sourceCon = builder.ConnectionString + ";Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;";
                    //Added spaces to retain password!!!
                    sourceCon = sourceCon.Replace(";", "; ");
                    connectionManager.ConnectionString = sourceCon;
                    Debug.WriteLine(connectionManager.ConnectionString.ToString());
                    break;
                case "DestinationConnection":
                    builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(sourceConnection) { PersistSecurityInfo = true };
                    builder.Remove("Initial Catalog");
                    builder.Add("Initial Catalog", "StagingArea");
                    var destCon = builder.ConnectionString + ";Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;";
                    //Added spaces to retain password!!!
                    destCon = destCon.Replace(";", "; ");
                    connectionManager.ConnectionString = destCon;
                    Debug.WriteLine(connectionManager.ConnectionString.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
}
```

I played about with the `ConnectionString`s and noticed after a while that the original `String` had spaces between each property.

Running 2 tests I found that without spaces the `Password` was lost...

```
connectionManager.ConnectionString = destCon;
```

**Test 1: No Spaces:**

When `destCon` = `Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=StagingArea;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;`

Then `connectionManager.ConnectionString` = `Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;User ID=*****;Initial Catalog=StagingArea;Provider=SQLNCLI;Auto Translate=false;`

**Test 2: Spaces:**

When `destCon` = `Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Initial Catalog=StagingArea; User ID=*****; Password=*****; Provider=SQLNCLI; Auto Translate=false;`

Then `connectionManager.ConnectionString` = `Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; Initial Catalog=StagingArea; User ID=*****; Password=*****; Provider=SQLNCLI; Auto Translate=false;`

No idea why this happens, but without spaces the ordering is adjusted and the `Password` field is lost.

Answer (score 2):

Set [PersistSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.persistsecurityinfo%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to True before setting other properties in the SqlConnectionStringBuilder : D

Comment: Thanks! This works for getting the String with the Password, but has uncovered another problem!